# WPF - Multibinding from Two Sources inside the ListBox DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, image, binding, listbox, itemssource

I tried to look around to see if I am missing something basic, but I can't seem to understand what I am doing wrong.

I have a listbox where I would like to bind the itemssource to a collectionview of photos from a dataset. The problem is, I need to take the directory where the images exist from the MasterView CollectionView, and the individual filenames from the DetailView CollectionView. So I defined the resources:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="MasterView" />
<CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource MasterView}, Path='tblGallery_tblPictures'}" x:Key="DetailView" />
```

This seems to work without a problem, I can navigate through the data set and see the Master and Detail data.

To get the full image path, I figured out that I needed a multibinding to put the two together, and have sucessfully created one:

```
 <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DetailView}}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
         <Image Width="120"
            Stretch="Uniform"
            Margin="8,8,8,8">
            <Image.Source>
              <BitmapImage DecodePixelWidth="120">
                <BitmapImage.UriSource>
                  <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource imagePathConverter}">
                    <Binding Source="{StaticResource MasterView}" Path="galleryLocation" />
                    <Binding Path="pictureFileName" />
                  </MultiBinding>
                 </BitmapImage.UriSource>
                </BitmapImage>
               </Image.Source>
             </Image>                        
          </DataTemplate>
       </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <ListBox.ItemsPanel>

     <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
     </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
 </ListBox>

 Public Function Convert(ByVal values() As Object, ByVal targetType As System.Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IMultiValueConverter.Convert

    If values.Count() <> 2 Then
        Throw New InvalidOperationException("Correct Values Not Provided")
    End If

    Dim directory As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim imgUri As Uri = Nothing

    If TypeOf values(0) Is String And TypeOf values(1) Is String Then
        directory = CType(values(0), String)
        fileName = CType(values(1), String)

        If directory <> "" And fileName <> "" Then
            If directory.LastIndexOf("/") = directory.Length - 1 Then
                imgUri = New Uri(directory & fileName, UriKind.Absolute)
            Else
                imgUri = New Uri(directory & "/" & fileName, UriKind.Absolute)
            End If

        End If
    End If

    Return (imgUri)

End Function
```

My assumption with the proceeding code, is that the MultiBinding that is inside the DataTemplate has access to the BindingSource that is defined as the
ItemsSource from the listbox. However when I look into the MultiValueConverter code it only passes the data from the MasterView and a generic object for the second value.

To see if I could get it to work, I added the detail source information in the multibinding:

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource imagePathConverter}">
  <Binding Source="{StaticResource MasterView}" Path="galleryLocation" />
  <Binding Source="{StaticResource DetailView}" Path="pictureFileName" />
</MultiBinding>
```

That at least enabled me to see that there were 5 pictures in the listbox, but they were all the same picture. It seems that the multibinding access to the DetailView CollectionView only showed the first item.

Is there a way to link the "pictureFileName" to the current ItemsSource item so that the right picture can be displayed?

thanks!

Josh

Comment: Ok, I tried to rule out some failure sources and took out the MultiBinding completely. Now I just have the link to DetailView DataSource:

    <Image.Source>
      <BitmapImage DecodePixelWidth="120" UriSource="{Binding Path=pictureFileName}" />
    </Image.Source>
          
However this does not work either. Again, when I add the Source to Binding (Source="{StaticResouce DetailView}") then I just get the first item repeated. In seeing some other questions, I can formulate my question a little better. 

How can I reference the Data that is bound to the ListBoxItem within the DataTemplate?